# A linear algebra fomula in Stanford online Machine Learning course

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, linear-algebra

Lecture 2 on http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1
at 59:47 you could see the last formula on the chalkboard:

`$\bigtriangledown_A tr ABA^TC = CAB + C^TAB^T  ...  (1)$`

and above that (in the middle of the chalkboard) there is:

`$\bigtriangledown_A tr AB = B^T ... (2) $`

apply (2) to (1) with substitution of changing $B$ in (2) to $BA^TC$ in left side of (1), we can get

`$\bigtriangledown_A tr ABA^TC = \bigtriangledown_A tr A(BA^TC) = (BA^TC)^T = C^TAB^T$`

in which the term `$CAB$` in (1) is missing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 A's in the expression, so you need to apply the product rule. See wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities